# can an XSD element be overloaded with multiple possible complex types?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a schema that defines an **event** record that is used to convey a message between two systems in a publish/subscribe scenario.  The event includes a "payload" element, **event_data**, with the details of the message.  The complication is that *the payload could be any of 30+ types*, each defined in its own XSD.

For example (stripped down):

```
<event>
   <event_name>new_phone_number</event_name>
   <event_data>
      <areacode>303</areacode>
      <number>555-1212</number>
      <extension>31</extension>
   </event_data>
</event>
```

In this case, the **event_data** is of type **phone_number**, which is defined elsewhere in an imported XSD.  But what I want to do is use the same mechanism to carry other kinds of structured message data.  E.g., maybe it's a job change event, defined as type **job_details**:

```
<event>
   <event_name>new_job</event_name>
   <event_data>
      <job_title>CEO</job_title>
      <start_date>01/01/2012</start_date>
      <location>Main Office</location>
   </event_data>
</event>
```

The inner record, stored in the **event_data** element, is of type **job_details**, as defined in an imported XSD. The "outer" record, of type **event**, is little more than a way to carry the payload contained in the "inner" record.

So far I have looked at three ways to attack this, each with problems:

1. Use a "choice" construct that lists all the possible record types.  The problem seems to be that it's not natural xml/xsd to have all entries in the choice list share the same element name.
2. I guess that rather than trying to include a structured subrecord in the **event_data** element, I could simply have an optional attribute reflecting every possible subrecord type.  Each would have a unique name, of course, so you'd have an attribute for **new_phone_number**, one for **new_job**, and so on.  Besides the potential maintainability and ugliness issues here, I'm not sure how I could enforce that one and only one of the attributes gets passed in a given instance of an event.  I could live with that, but it makes the code fragile.
3. Someone answered a similar question by suggesting use of a union - but that seems to apply only to simple types.  Wouldn't cover my use case.

Stumped!  Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using an `xsi:type` override in your instance document. XML processors cannot "infer" types, you need to provide this. Example:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <event>
     <event_name>new_phone_number</event_name>
     <event_data xsi:type="PhoneNumberData">
        <areacode>303</areacode>
        <number>555-1212</number>
        <extension>31</extension>
     </event_data>
  </event>
</root>
```

Note that you have to define a base complex type `EventData` and `PhoneNumberData` must derive from this, for this to work.

Comment: That's interesting - thanks!  So since my types are really diverse, having very few elements at all in common, the base type would be extremely thin, right?  I would derive the specific types by extending that with an xs:extension block?

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 (implemented in Xerces and Saxon), you can do this using the feature called "conditional type assignment", whereby at the level of an element declaration you decide which type to use from a list of alternatives selected by applying an XPath expression to the element's attributes.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you happen to know if BizTalk supports xsd 1.1?  I have been looking through the BizTalk stuff and not finding it....that's my destination platform, with a Ruby pub-sub client.

Comment: XSD 1.1 is very recent, in fact it's not even finished yet, and Microsoft aren't noted for implementing new standards in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into using [substitution groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/#SubsGroups) although it doesn't probably suit your problem as well as the two previously suggested ones. Substitution groups are more like "using a specific element instead of a generic element" whereas your problem seems to be more something like "using a specific type instead of a generic type".